# Need a copy of value. No need referenced value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just need to copy the value of `data.notes`. I have used below code. But still `detailsOfCurrentNotes` value changes according to the value of `data.notes`. So could you tell me how to do this?

`notes :Note[]`

```
 const detailsOfCurrentNotes = Object.assign({}, data.notes);
 //here data.notes changes
 // detailsOfCurrentNotes also get that value
```

Comment: Assuming that notes is an array, try with `const detailsOfCurrentNotes = [...data.notes]`.

Comment: @Striped that wont work if notes is an object.

Comment: @AyushGupta I've updated the comment, assuming the notes is an array.

Comment: The duplicate was the first result after 10 seconds of searching...

Comment: Almost all answers from the duplicate work with arrays. How about first giving it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object/array is not circular, you can simply do:

```
const detailsOfCurrentNotes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.notes));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `notes` is an array, it is:

```
const detailsOfCurrentNotes = Object.assign([], data.notes);
```

And shorter syntax is:

```
const detailsOfCurrentNotes = [...data.notes];
```

This creates shallow copy of an array.

Comment: And a shallow copy is cleary not what TO is asking for: _"But still `detailsOfCurrentNotes` value changes according to the value of `data.notes`"_

Comment: @Andreas The question isn't clear enough about the details, so reading OP's thoughts is a bit far-fetched